# I need a regular expression to detect MailChimp tags

Tags: c#, regex

I have an html string that I need to pass through a regular expression. This expression has to detect MailChimp tags in the format: `*|TagName|*`

I am not too familiar with regular expressions. What I am currently using is: `\*\|([^]]*)\|\*`

But his regular expression detects the while string between 2 matches. So if we have:

`"Sample text with user *|User_Name|*, to verify regular expression with *|Date_Value|*, and some other text"`,

the match would be:

```
 "*|User_Name|*, to verify regular expression with *|Date_Value|*"
```

If someone can tell me how to change the expression or what to use instead to detect all matches separately.

Thank you

Comment: i think it will help \*\|\w+\|\*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try this regular expression:

```
  string source = 
    "Sample text with user *|User_Name|*, to verify regular expression with *|Date_Value|*, and some other text";

  string pattern = @"\*\|.*?\|\*"; // please, notice ".*?" instead of ".*"

  // ["*|User_Name|*", "*|Date_Value|*"]
  string[] matches = Regex
    .Matches(source, pattern)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

The trick is in the `.*?` instead of `.*` - match as **few** letters as possible

Comment: Intuitively I'd go for the regex `\*\|[^*|]+\|\*`, i.e. use a negated character class. As far as I can tell the outcome will be almost the same (your regex allows empty tags). Is there an advantage in using the non-greedy `?` over a negated character class?

Comment: @Abbondanza: I doubt if there're much difference in performance, but non-greedy is IMHO more readable.